# Scrollbar of a overflown div shown above child div with higher z-index only in Chromium-based browsers

Tags: html, css

I have two `divs` with `position: fixed;`, with one as the child of the other. Using `z-index`, I lay one of them over the other. The `div` in the back additionally uses an `overflow: auto;` in order to have a scrollbar when there is to much content.

The problem I now have is, that in Chromium-based browsers the generated scrollbar appears over the child `div`. In other browsers, like Firefox, the child `div` is shown above the scrollbar.

My goal is to have the Chromium-based browsers behave the same as Firefox, with the scrollbar hidden behind the child `div`.

```css
#main{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 106;
  position: fixed;
}

#overlay{
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
  <div id="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsFiddle to show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/4pfc3anx/7/

I have seen that when I move the child `div` outside of the parent `div`, the behaviour changes to be my intended behaviour, this is however not practical with the current code-base and I would prefer a CSS-only solution.

How can I change my code to make the Chromium-based browser look like the firefox ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position: fixed;` from `#main`. `z-index` also not needed.

```css
#main{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#overlay{
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
  <div id="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE for #main fixed position**

Wrap text in `#main` with something (e.g. `div`) with `height: 100%;` and replace `overflow-y: auto;` from `#main` `css` to this element.

Always good practice to wrap text with element, it gives more opportunities to manipulate.

```css
#main {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  </div>
  <div id="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE possible solutions for keeping fixed position**

- Make scrollbar invisible. (I added shadows to top and bottom to identify, that there is scrollable content, from some solution from SO. But of course if bottom goes under the entire page when `main` has big hight, it is not visible)

```css
#main {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 106;
  position: fixed;
  
  outline: dashed 1px blue;
}

#main::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
}

#main {
  background: /* Shadow covers */
  linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 70%) 0 100%, /* Shadows */
  radial-gradient(50% 0, farthest-side, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(50% 100%, farthest-side, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
  background: /* Shadow covers */
  linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 70%) 0 100%, /* Shadows */
  radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: 100% 40px, 100% 40px, 100% 14px, 100% 14px;
  /* Opera doesn't support this in the shorthand */
  background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  <div id="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

- Move scrollbar to the left side.

```css
#main {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 106;
  position: fixed;
  direction: rtl;
}

#main .ltr {
  direction: ltr;
  display: flex;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <span class="ltr">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  </span>
  <div id="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but since the case is integrated into an entire website, it also changes the layout of the entire site when I remove position: fixed from main. Do you know of another way?

Comment: The difference is visible when increasing the height of the main div. When it is larger than the height of the window, a scrollbar for the entire page will show. In the original question, this scrollbar for the entire page is not visible at any height of the main div.

Comment: @DominikB can't figure out for now, made update in answer with possible solutions. But it seems, that your website sctructure is quit strange and could be restructured.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it really does not seem to work as long as the div is a child of the div with the overflow. I'm going to have to move the overlay div outside.